# Dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 8.1 goes straight to windows

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

I installed Ubuntu on my Lenovo y510p a few months ago and it worked fine.
Yesterday i entered Windows and right at startup i got a blue screen of death and afterwords when the computer restarted i saw a message that went something along:"no bootable file, enter USB" (or something like this).

I restarted the computer again and it wend straight to windows, no purple screen to choose what OS to boot to.

Windows works fine.

I did not find any other thread about problems of this sort.
What can i do?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Answer (score 0):

Use "boot-repair disk" google it. It is live CD about 600mb. Mandatory condition is it should be connected with WiFi before repairing boot loader.It will automatically scan your all bootable drives and will give you instructions on the spot. A menu will come where mouse will not work. In that condition you have to use tab to move courser and space to select. Your problem will be solved if you will not make changes in Grub manually. Reason is in mostly cases manual changes are not understood by "boot-repair disk".

When on windows installed system, we install Ubuntu, it automatically gives option to create dual boot for both systems but if Ubuntu is pre-installed and we are adding windows to our system then it stops the grub of Ubuntu. So this crash of grub of Ubuntu was obvious.